# Why is order of declaration not an issue in this python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just wondering what the actual explanation is as to why this is valid python.

foo.py

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        if type(self).__name__ in MAP.keys():
            print('WOO HOOO')
        self.Bar = True

MAP = {'Foo': Foo}
```

test

```
>>> from foo import *
>>> x = Foo()
WOO HOOO
```

I would have thought that the MAP dict when referenced in the constructor would be invalid. 
Is this due to the fact that the constructor is only checked at run-time?

Comment: The code inside `__init__` itself is only _executed_ after the import has been done and the class is instantiated (by which time, `MAP` already exists in the module's scope), it is not executed when the class definition is being executed during import.  This is what you already hint at in the question.

Comment: When you define `MAP`, you're not calling `Foo`. If you changed it to `{'Foo': Foo()}` then you'd get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `MAP` is only looked up when `__init__` is run.

If it helps you understand, let's strip away all the non-essential info:

1. It's irrelevant that `__init__` is a method. You can get the same behaviour with a function.
2. The value of `MAP` is not important; we just want to check whether it exists
3. Let's also see what happens when `MAP` doesn't exist, using a try-except-else.
4. Put everything in one script
5. `self.Bar` and `x` are unused

```
def foo():
    try:
        MAP
    except NameError:
        print('No!')
    else:
        print('Yes!')

foo()  # -> No!
MAP = 0
foo()  # -> Yes!
```